# R : stat_smooth groups (x axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, stat

I have a [Database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zK9xcdOi1sMERxTTFmd2lLWjg/view?usp=sharing), and want to show a figure using stat_smooth.

I can show the avg_time vs Scored_Probabilities figure, which looks like this:

```
c <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Avg.time, y=Scored.Probabilities))
c + stat_smooth()
```

[image]

But when changing Avg.time to time or Age, an error occurs:

```
c <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Age, y=Scored.Probabilities))
c + stat_smooth()
error: geom_smooth: Only one unique x value each group. Maybe you want aes(group = 1)?
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: `stat_smooth` only works with continuous variables. Your `age` variable is a character variable. I can only assume that the `time` variable is also not saved as time, but character instead. You first have to convert your variables to numeric in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the error message says to set `group=1`, doing that gives another error

```
ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Age, y=Scored.Probabilities, group=1))+stat_smooth()
geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
Error in smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, data, knots) : 
  x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k.
```

Now the number of unique `x` values is not enough.

So two solutions : i) using another function like `mean`, ii) using jitter to move slightly Age.

```
ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=Age, y=Scored.Probabilities, group=1))+
geom_point()+
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line", size = 3) # draw a mean line in the data
```

[image]

Or

```
ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=jitter(as.numeric(as.character(Age))), y=Scored.Probabilities, group=1))+
geom_point()+stat_smooth()
```

Note the use of `as.numeric` because `Age` is a factor.

[image]

Comment: on a factor use `as.numeric(as.character(variable))`,  `as.numeric(variable)` may not return the expected value

Comment: you are probably right, feel free to edit the answer